# Archer GRC Automated Deployments

Tags: continuous-deployment, rsa-archer-grc

I am trying to figure out if Automated Deployments for Archer GRC is possible for the On Prem version ?

Currently it is deployed manually.

Comment: Are you talking about deploying packages automatically or installation of Archer itself like an unattended install? Also what version of Archer are on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Latest version of Archer (v6.8, v6.9) has limited API provided to allow package deployments, BUT last time I checked they don't allow mapping and partial installs (I can be wrong, so double check).
API is there, but functionality is limited to the point that I don't see how package installation can be automated via provided API. I hope that in the next Archer versions it will be extended to replicate the functionality available with manual package deployment (mapping, partial installs, and other options).

Technically, if you like complex and time consuming tasks, you can decode/parse the package installation page. Then you can write an application to simulate HTTP packets sent to Archer server simulating the package installation.
I'm not aware of any company doing something like this as of today.
If you write a product to implement proper Code/Configuration Version Control for RSA Archer, then you may be able to sell it as well :)

Good luck!